# Django url routing - include url part for dispatching

Tags: python, django

can i substitute the 2 url routes

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',        
    url(r'service/geticons', 'core.service.geticons'),
    url(r'service/getnearby', 'core.service.getnearby'),
```

by a single, more generic, route that routes all requests to the function in the service module with the name of the last url segment?

thinking about something like

```
    url(r'service/#f', 'core.service.#f')
```

or must i do such dispatch in the service module in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could collect the path and point it to a view that returns the function.

```
url(r'service/(?P<function>\w+)/$', 'core.service.function_router')


def function_router(request, function):
    return globals()[function](request)
```

But, it's probably better just to explicitly set the urls.

Comment: thx, i was quite sure that there is no better way. also for showing the dispatcher function. in asp.net mvc and i believe in pylon such generic routes are easy and prove useful in practice. for django i agee with your advice and will go for separate url routes for each service function. are not too many anyway. thx again!

Comment: Hey thomas, yes I believe explicit is the best way to go until there's a true bottleneck or problem with that system